# Intellisense not working in Visual Studio for Sql Server Data Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-data-project

I am trying to switch from SSMS to Visual Studio using Sql Server Data Project, as I like the Project/Solution structure to organize related scripts.

However, I seem to be unable to get Intellisense to work as expected.

I am expecting to be able to connect to a database, and then type

`Select * from Account a where a.` and get a list of fields for the account table.  This works just fine in SSMS.

However, in VS, I get no list of fields.  [image: This is what it looks like for me]

I have ensured that Intellisense is enable for Sql Server Data Projects here:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this type of Intellisense not supported?